# Unable to fetch query params in Angular4

Tags: angular, navigation, angular4-router, query-string

I am developing an Angular4 application using primeng library. In one of my component I have the following code:

```
  navigateUrl(company:any, cause?:boolean) {
    let navigationExtras = {queryParams : {cause: false}};
    let navigateToUrl = '/home/policy/menu/' +
    company.policyId+ '/' + encodeURIComponent(company.name) + '/' +
    company.companyId + '/branches';
    if(cause) {
      let navigationExtras = {queryParams : {cause: true}};
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl(navigateToUrl, navigationExtras);
  }
```

I am trying to fetch these queryParams in the upcoming menu component like:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
});
```

also I have tried

```
this.route.queryParams['cause'];
```

But whatever I try, I always get a blank map for the query params.
Can someone point out where am I going wrong.

Comment: why `navigateByUrl`? why not just `navigate`?

Answer (score 1):

try

`this.router.navigate(['/home/policy/menu/'], navigationExtras);` instead of  `this.router.navigateByUrl(navigateToUrl, navigationExtras);`

or try this

`this.router.navigateByUrl(navigateToUrl, navigationExtras.queryParams);`

> But you should provide the validate route name, So you need to check  `/home/policy/menu/` is a valid route name.